# c# Variable Reset to 0 At Switch

Tags: c#

OK so I am new to c# so bear with me!

This code works to a degree:

```
                    if (rng.Value != null)
                    {
                        string cellValue = rng.Value.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string cellValue = "Null";
                    }


                    switch (cCnt)
                    {
                        case 1:
```

So this gets the value from an Excel sheet cell by cell and puts it into cellValue, unless it is empty.

All is fine when I step through it in debug until it gets to the switch, when the value for cellValue then gets set to 0 every time, even when there is valid data.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `cCnt` is what you are switching on, not `cellValue` - it's unclear what you are asking (also `cellValue` does not exist outside of the `if` and `else` blocks)

Comment: How is `cellValue` even accessible at the `switch` statement?  It's only declared inside the if/else blocks.  How are you observing that it's set to `0`?  What do you expect it to be set to?  Why?

Comment: It would help to see the entire switch statement.

Answer (score 3):

The concept you're missing here is called **scope**.

The `cellValue` variable is declared inside the `if` and `else` blocks, meaning it has gone out of scope by the time you get to the `switch` block. You want to declare that variable above the `if` block, so it will have a larger scope.

```
string cellValue = "Null";
if (rng.Value != null)
{
    cellValue = rng.Value.ToString();
}

switch (cCnt)
{
    case 1:
```

Comment: Ok, I don't get one thing, why everyone, when seeing someone with high reputation answering (no matters what), always upvoting automatically? We all understand, that it could be hes declaring his variable again (because its not accessible in `switch` block). But please  point a right way to OP to update his code, note assume something, then write it in answer.

Comment: I upvoted as it answered my question and solved the issue.  Not familiar with c# so wasn't aware of scope.

Comment: @davidjwest Actually this question should be marked as _off topic - seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")_ and be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration is within `if` block. Change to:

```
string cellValue = string.Empty;

if (rng.Value != null)
{
    cellValue = rng.Value.ToString();
}
else
{
    cellValue = "Null";
}

switch (cCnt)
{
    case 1:
```